# Plotting geostrophic wind plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working on an assignment that is teaching how to plot and label using matplotlib using Python. Science or math is not my background. I have been given the formula for calculating the geostrophic wind and we are to plot it (on the y-axis) versus the latitude on the x-axis.

I know how to plot give an x and a y. Beyond that, the formula is not making sense to me given my lack of background in the area.

The formula is the geostrophic wind formula. Because all I have is an image and I need 10 rep to post an image, I'll just focus on the greek letters I am given.

For example, I am given

```
r'$x^{10}$'
r'$R_^{final}$'
r'$alpha^{\eta}$'
```

The first two are superscript and subscript. That I understand. But how this helps with the formula calculations I do not know.

I am given the values to put into the formula as well. An explanation of the order of operations would help.

```
g0=9.81 ms-­‐2;
ΔZ=60m;
Δn=2x10^5m;
and
f=2Ωsin(φ)
```

My question is how do I put the values above into the formula and then plot them in matplotlib? is it as easy as x and y?

Example of plotting done so far:

```
x = arange(1, 100, 1)
y1 = 2.0*np.sqrt(x)
y2 = 3.0*x**(1.0/3.0)
plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
```

Sorry, I'm new to this.

[geostrophic wind formula](http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m201/geostrophy/GeostrophicWind_files/image006.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical explanation in [jclark754's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31200855/512111) is good. Look at the [wiki page on Geostrophic wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostrophic_wind), too.

`$\Delta n$` is, I assume, your northward distance. I call it `dy` below, for clarification. Also, it is a question whether you should take `g` to be negative (z-axis upward). I do so.

For the code, you need to be aware that `np.sin` expects **radians** rather than degrees.

And if you work with [NumPy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) rather than lists, you do not need all those list comprehensions and the formulation gets much simpler and closer to the formula:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ; plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np

# define the parameters
g = -9.81 # m/s^2
dZ = 60 # m
dx = 2e5 # m
omega = 7.2921e-5 # rad/s
phi = np.linspace(10,40) # deg
f = 2 * omega * np.sin(np.radians(phi)) # coriolis frequency, s^-1

# compute geostrophic wind, x-component
u_g = -1. * g/f * dZ/dx

# plot phi vs V_g
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(phi, u_g)
ax.set_xlabel('latitude (degrees)')
ax.set_ylabel('geostrophic wind, y-component (m/s)')
plt.show()
```

[image: geostrophic wind as a function of latitude]

The plot shows the geostrophic wind resulting from a constant geostrophic height gradient (`dZ/dx = 60 m / 2e5 m`) and the Coriolis effect, at different latitudes.

From physical intuition, I find it strange that the velocity increases as you get closer to the equator, even though the Coriolis effect is strongest towards the poles. But then again, the Coriolis effect is not a force but more a balancing effect, obstructing the release of potential energy contained in the pressure gradient force.

Comment: Thank you! This was the correct line. The axes were a bit off, but that was my fault for not specifying.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe the equation you're trying to show is the geostrophic wind equation:
[image: geostrophic wind eq]

Is that it? If so, it's one of the simpler equations in meteorology and I'd be happy to explain!

**Vg** is the geostrophic wind, it's a theoretical wind that results from a balance between the Coriolis effect and the pressure gradient force. It's an idealized wind that doesn't really exist in nature.

**g0** and **f** are gravity and the Coriolis parameter. The Coriolis parameter is a necessary correction needed to account for the Coriolis force.

**grad(h)** and **Z** are just the height gradient per degree of latitude. In your case, you're provided with 60 meters as Z and I'm unsure what Δn is for. Maybe your instructor is saying that the change is 60 meters per 2x10^5 meters? I'll assume that's the case.

So just calculating this in wolfram alpha for Denver, Colorado's latitude (40 deg), I get 31.39 meters per second, which is a reasonable number.

Let's try to plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a list of latitudes but exclude the equator because sin(0) is 0
lat_list = [i for i in range(-90, 91) if i != 0]

# Create a list of coriolis values
cor_list = [2 * 7.292e-5 * np.sin(i) for i in lat_list]

# Create a list of geostrophic winds
geo_wind = [(9.81 / i) * (60.0 / 200000.0) for i in cor_list]

# Plot the geostrophic winds on a line 
# Make a new plot, with lat as x and wind as y. 'r--' is a red dashed line
plt.plot(lat_list, geo_wind, 'r--')
# set the axis range
plt.axis([-90, 90, min(geo_wind), max(geo_wind)])
# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Would give you the following chart, where latitude is the x-axis and wind speed is the y-axis:
[image]

Oddly, the chart (and printing the geo_wind list) show some wind value calculations exceeding 100 m/s and in some cases over 1000 m/s. I'm unsure why that's the case right now...it's a bit late! So the logic is correct, I would just check how python is calculating the wind speed...I'm think it has to do with scientific notation and floating point numbers.

Anyway, I should note that I wrote the above lists as list comprehensions. If that's a bit over your head, it's ok. Check out this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for a good explanation on how they compare to regular lists/for loops. I hope this gets you off to a good start. Happy trails!

Comment: Wow, thanks. Unfortunately, the graph does not match. However, you have the right formula. The graph I wish I could show you. It's a slope downwards. X-Axis is 10- 90 which is easy enough. It is just the Y-Axis. Let me look over what you got though.

Comment: ok, i see what you did there with the code, which is what i needed so I can troubleshoot this. I understand your explanation a little bit. It's just a matter of setting the right parameters, which are different. Thank you very much. I am reading now about the for loop stuff in the link as well. I'm sure there was a simple solution, it's just the formula through me off.

Comment: You make a few mistakes here. First of all, `np.sin` takes an angle in **radians** rather than degrees. That explains the weird spikes in the plot. If you check out the [wiki article on Geostropic Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostrophic_wind), you can get some explanation for what $\Delta n$ is here. It is the horizontal distance (weird naming choice, should be $\Delta x$). Finally, generate sequences with `np.linspace` rather than `range`.

Comment: @j08lue, I'm glad you came along! Thanks for the heads up on the numpy stuff...I was about to go to bed and saw the weather stuff and felt the itch to test my memory. Appreciate you cleaning things up!